# SQL trigger on recursive table

Tags: mysql, triggers, recursive-datastructures

I have this database structure :

[Designer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QcKLc.png)

I'm trying to implement this trigger so when a thread has reply, the number_replies goes up on every insertion of a thread if the parentId is not NULL

```
DELIMITER $$ 
CREATE TRIGGER `reply_count` AFTER INSERT ON `threads` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    IF NEW.parentId != NULL THEN
UPDATE
    threads
SET
    threads.number_replies = threads.number_replies + 1
WHERE
    threads.id = NEW.parentId;
END IF ; 
END $$ DELIMITER ;
```

I don't get any errors but it is not working. Thoughts?

Comment: You try to alter the data in the table which event fires the trigger. This is absolutely impossible.

Comment: So a separate table for replies would work?

Comment: Yes, another table may be updated.

Comment: Yes, I just tried it and it works. Thanks!